# Unable to deploy outlook add-in to EWS server

Tags: visual-studio, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, multi-factor-authentication

I developed an outlook add-in in visual studio. I am able to deploy it in EWS servers which doesn't require MFA authentication but facing authentication issue to deploy on EWS server which need Multi-factor authentication.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw4dK.png)

Comment: What type of add-in is it ? eg VSTO Com+ based (or Modern Addin) and what does your code look like (eg the authentication part) ?

Comment: Hi Glen, It is a modern addin which uses a graph API that is an registered app in Azure AD.

Comment: Can you show some of your code because your questions a little confused in your comment you mention the graph API while you question is about EWS. You also mention EWS Server so is this Office365 or OnPrem (for the Graph API it would need to be Office365)